# How to view data decode json in blade

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I have data like this
result from

```
dd($data)
```

in blade

```
array:18 [▼
"id" => "5dbb3b9adbc24572692f50e1"
"external_id" => "T Shirt Cyber Jawara"
"user_id" => "5785e6334d7b410667d355c4"
"status" => "PENDING"
"merchant_name" => "Xendit Testing"
"merchant_profile_picture_url" => "https://www.xendit.co/images/logo.png"
"amount" => 300000
"payer_email" => "hendro@gmail.com"
"description" => "BayarT Shirt Cyber Jawara"
"expiry_date" => "2019-11-01T19:52:58.423Z"
]
```

data is from controller

```
return view('confirmorder',['data' => $responseObject]);
```

How to show in blade laravel?

Comment: In blade you can `{{ $data['id'] }}` or any other array key: `{{ $data['external_id'] }}` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I fully understood what you need, but to pass data to your blade view is simple. Just do something like so:

```
public function returnView()
{
    $responseObject = [
        "id" => "5dbb3b9adbc24572692f50e1",
        "external_id" => "T Shirt Cyber Jawara",
        "user_id" => "5785e6334d7b410667d355c4",
        "status" => "PENDING",
        "merchant_name" => "Xendit Testing",
        "merchant_profile_picture_url" => "https://www.xendit.co/images/logo.png",
        "amount" => 300000,
        "payer_email" => "hendro@gmail.com",
        "description" => "BayarT Shirt Cyber Jawara",
        "expiry_date" => "2019-11-01T19:52:58.423Z"
    ];

    return view('confirmorder', compact('responseObject'));
}
```

Then, on your blade view, you will be able to call the array however you want, like so:

```
{{ $responseObject['status'] }}
```

Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: how I write in page blade view? with your code? @lucasArbex

Comment: @idnsainfo like I wrote on the updated version of the answer: `{{ $responseObject['status'] }}`...

Comment: @idnsainfo please, try it now, and let me know if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Just use {{ $data }} in the view

for a specific key,
{{ $data['user_id'] }}